# Помогите разобраться с ошибками с проектом на Visual Studio

Tags: c++, winforms

Подскажите куда смотреть в Debug все работает при Release выскакивают ошибки 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотреть в свойства проекта. Вероятно, lib-файлы добавлены только в дебажную сборку.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Спасибо, вы были правы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотреть в свойства проекта. lib-файлы добавлены только в дебажную сборку.